# jQuery Countdown with use of PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, countdown

*The idea:* To create a countdown to show days or hours left until some event (no minutes or seconds are required)...

I have MySQL database which stores data used by countdown: id, date & description.
I have a PHP file to get it all from database and output it into HTML

*How it looks:*

**HTML Output:**

```
<span>2 Days</span> Until Some Event!
```

**PHP Code:**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM countdowns ORDER BY id DESC",$connect);
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<div class=\"countdown\">";
        echo "<span>";
            echo $myrow['date'];
        echo "</span> ";
        echo $myrow['description'];
    echo "</div>";
```

So I want 'span' to dispaly days OR hours and rest will be description pulled from the database.

*The problem:* I want it to display **ONLY** days if hours are greater than 48 or **ONLY** hours if there are less than 48 hours left.

*So it should look like:*

5 Days Until Some Event! *(There are more than 48 hours left)*

**OR**

5 Hours Until Some Event! *(There are obviously less than 48 hours left)*

Why I need jQuery for this is because the page on which this countdown will be shown, will be active for days without reloading, so I need it to be dynamic...

I hope you can understand what I mean and probably could help me, thank you very much in advance!

*Andrew Badger*

Comment: do you have any draft php scripts? what king of answer do you wait? you want smbd to write this all for you?

Comment: @heximal I have edited my question with PHP code, sorry for not doing it in the first place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use a plugin like [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) and change it so that instead of writing the time eladsed from a timestamp it shows the time missing to a timestamp.

EDIT - maybe you don't need to change any part of the code but just set this settings

```
jQuery.timeago.settings.allowFuture = true;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the plugin you have linked looks pretty interesting, I will have a play with it later... Maybe it will work the way I need.

Comment: This plugin did everything I needed! Thank you very much Nicola.